# Phpize: cannot find build files

Tags: linux, php, php5, debian-squeeze

I'm getting the following error when trying `phpize` for Thrift:

```
# phpize
Cannot find build files at '/usr/local/lib/php/build'. Please check your PHP installation.
```

I **have** installed `php5-dev`. I've tried both the php5.3 version fromt the official dist, and I've also tried the php5.4 version from the dotdeb squeeze php54 dist.

Specs:

- Debian 6.0 (Squeeze)
- Apache 2.2.16
- PHP 5.4.16-1

Comment: The problem described here **can no longer be reproduced**. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by reinstalling PHP.